# Get all functions with parameters from string using XRegExp library

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, npm-install, xregexp

I am working on regular expression.
for this, I am using XRegExp library.

I have a string like

```
"Hello#".concat( "my#world".substring( "my#world".indexOf('#') ,  "my#world".length()))
```

I want to get all functions from the string with parameters.

For example: for above string, XRegExp should return concat, substring, indexOf functions with respected parameters

I am trying using below expression as

```
 var resultObject= XRegExp.matchRecursive(expreesionString, 'concat|trim\\(', '\\)', 'gi', {
valueNames: ['between', 'left', 'match', 'right']
```

});

but it is throwing an error.

Also trying to get prefix string for the function
Please suggest some help for better result

Comment: Well, you need to pass regexps to the XRegExp, so you need to use `'\\)'` as the trailing delimiter pattern. I think the initial `/` is a typo and should be removed.

Comment: I have tried with "concat|trim\\\(', '\\\)" but still not working

Comment: It is jsut returning parameter of first function XRegExp.matchRecursive(expreesionString, '\\\(', '\\\)', 'gi', {
    valueNames: [null, null, 'match', null]
});